# jQuery selector in included php file not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I made a simple website to manage and display items. For my problem is sufficient to know that there are 3 files:

1. `admin-dashboard.php` which display items and admin functionalities (reduce quantity, increase ecc.)

```html
<?php
 include("includes/header.php");
 include("dbqueries/db-connection.php");
 include("includes/alerts.php");
?>
...
```

2. `dashboard-utilities.js` which contains all the JavaScript functions to realize point 1

```js
...
// Reduce quantity button script
function reduceQuantity(item) {
 $.ajax({
     method: 'get',
     url: '../dbqueries/reduceQuantity.php',
     data: {
         'current_item': item,
     },
     success: function() {
      //alert("Quantità di " + "\"" + item + "\"" + " diminuita!");
      $('#reduceqty-modal').modal('show'); 
      // Reload page after closing the modal alert
      $('#reduceqty-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        window.location.reload();
      })
     }
 });
}
...
```

3. `alerts.php` which will contain all the bootstrap modal alerts to display on operations success (i.e. "Quantity updated!")

```html
<!-- Reduce quantity modal -->
<div id="reduceqty-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Quantità ridotta</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

So the problem is that the "success" part of the `reduceQuantity` function is not working. In particular the modal is not displayed.

I supposed that jQuery cannot find its selector cause it is in the included file (`alerts.php`). I think so because if I put the alert code directly into the main file `admin-dashboard.php` everything works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How (and where) does `dashboard-utilities.js` get included? is there a `<script` tag somewhere?

Comment: _"I supposed that jQuery cannot find its selector cause it is in the included file (alerts.php)") ...that shouldn't be a problem, as long as the HTML from alerts.php is loaded into the page before the `reduceQuantity()` function is executed. And it should be, if all those files are included by PHP, then they should all be sent to the browser at the same time and loaded when the page first loads. Only problem would be if `reduceQuantity()` is executed immediately when the script tag loads, before the browser had chance to load the HTML for the modal.

Comment: P.S. do you have any errors in your console? Does other code in the "success" part work? e.g. if you add other commands in there (e.g. to alert(), or console.log)

Comment: First of all thank you. 
`dashboard-utilities.js` is included before the `<body>` closure of `admin-dashboard.php`.
No errors in console. And `reduceQuantity` works, the only thing that's not working is the modal.

Comment: Where are the `<html` `<head` and `<body` tags of the HTML, relative to your `<include` statements? I'm wondering if the HTML of the modal is outside the document somehow.

Comment: As a little test, write `console.log($('#reduceqty-modal').length);` in the "success" function. It'll tell us if jQuery has managed to locate the HTML element for the modal, or not. If length is 0, it hasn't found it.

Comment: The result is 0! Maybe I have to include `alerts` directly into the `header` php script.

Comment: I don't know if that's necessary or not. What's important is that it's included somewhere within your `<body>...</body>` tags, and that the rest of the HTML around it is valid too (so that it isn't accidentally within another unclosed tag or something that like, making it invisible to the browser).

Comment: To cover this point: *"I supposed that jQuery cannot find its selector cause it is in the included file (alerts.php)."* - jquery sees what the browser sees - and that's a *single* HTML file.  As long as the "included file" is being output, then jquery will be able to see it - so it looks like it's not being included/output.  Try a view-source to see if your modal is there.  You can also remove some of the classes (eg class=modal) and you should see it in the rendered output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... The problem was related to the server. The file `alerts.php` didn't have the correct permissions and the correct owner. I noticed it when you said that it wasn't probably really included.

Sorry for wasting your time, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like the `reduceQuantity()` function cannot find the modal element, because the function is running before the HTML element has been parsed. This could either be because you need to wrap your JQuery in a `$(document).ready(function(){})` or you need to include the Javascript at the end of your `admin-dashboard.php` file (before the closing `</body>` tag) and then put the `alerts.php` at the top so that it can be parsed before the Javascript runs. You might need to do both of these things.

Comment: Thank you, but it was already set up as you are saying. The problem was related to server-side file permissions. The `alerts.php` file was not readable by others, so it can't be included (it practically didn't exist for the browser).

Comment: Aaaah I see! I'm glad you got it fixed @AlanQuaino =)